# SOAPUI:- Multiple Invalid HTTP status code Assertion

Tags: soapui, assertions

I am adding multiple "Invalid HTTP Status code" assertion as shown below

[image]

> Expected Behaviour:- Test Step should fail if HTTP 503 code is returned.
>   Actual Behaviour:- Test step is getting passed.

If assertion added as

> 503;400

Test step is getting failed and is working as expected.

I am not sure why it is taking only the first HTTP code though the format for multiple HTTP code looks correct.

Anything i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the example in [official documentation](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/secure/assertions/type/http_invalid) the list of invalid *HTTP Status code* is separated by `;`:

[image]

However using `;`, its doesn't work.

I make some tries and I can make it work using `,` instead.

So try with: `400, 503` as list for invalid *HTTP Status code*.

Hope it helps,

Comment: @sushantkumar nice to help you `:)`. I also found [another documentation](https://www.soapui.org/security-testing/overview-of-security-scans.html#3-2-Valid-HTTP-Codes) from SOAPUI where it use `,` correctly.

Comment: yeah but the link they attached within tool it opens wrong document :)

Comment: @sushantkumar of course, I only post the link to confirm that something is wrong with documentation `:)`

Comment: Apparently the developers were thinking of email "To" separators and not a normal list separator O_o